# Rotate and lap words

Tags: positioning

I want to rotate the word flower 5 times and the rotations should lap over the c. That's what I got so far:

```
\clap{\rotatebox[origin=c]{0}{flower}}\clap{\rotatebox[origin=c]{20}
    {flower}}\clap{\rotatebox[origin=c]{45}{flower}}
    \clap{\rotatebox[origin=c]{60}{flower}}\clap{\rotatebox[origin=c]{80}{flower}}
```

Could somebody please help me?

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187509/overlaping-text-or-text-above-text/

Answer (score 7):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
  \makebox[0pt][c]{\rotatebox[origin=c]{0}{flower}}%
  \makebox[0pt][c]{\rotatebox[origin=c]{22.5}{flower}}%
  \makebox[0pt][c]{\rotatebox[origin=c]{45}{flower}}%
  \makebox[0pt][c]{\rotatebox[origin=c]{67.5}{flower}}%
  \makebox[0pt][c]{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{flower}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here there are two things. `\makebox[<alignment>]` will take `<alignment>` as `l` or `c` or `r` as values. And `\rotatebox`, according to the manual of `graphicx`:

[image]

Hence you can play with all of these options.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\rotatebox{0}{flower}}%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\rotatebox{22.5}{flower}}%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\rotatebox{45}{flower}}%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\rotatebox{67.5}{flower}}%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\rotatebox{90}{flower}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: And what, if I want to rotate the word at the first letter and it should lap there? Do I replace the c with l?

Comment: I've taken the liberty of (a) reformatting your input code to make it easier to parse visually and (b) adding `%` symbols to suppress unwanted insertions of whitespace.

Comment: But that's nota big difference, right?

Comment: @maggie - The original form of Harish's code introduced an extra space between the third and fourth occurrence of "flower".

Comment: @Mico -- you put the `%`s in the code, but the visuals still show the output with the unwanted extra space.  (there's a clear disjunction between the third and fourth "r"s, where they should end on a common arc.

Comment: @barbarabeeton - I've changed the images to go with the (modified) code.

Comment: @Mico -- looks much better.  however, it just occurred to me that showing the "with space" version and the fixed one side by side would be instructive.  (not suggesting a change though.  but there may be some venue where such a demonstration would be useful and appropriate.  maybe a question here about "what problems might arise because a `&` is omitted?"  this "fan" would be a really good illustration.

Comment: @barbarabeeton - Why don't you post just such a question and let the answers pour in? :-)  (BTW, should that be a `%` instead of a `&` symbol in the final sentence of your comment?)

Comment: @Mico -- oh, obviously it should be a `%`.  since i've been much delayed by a "system failure" (actually, the failure of software because of system changes), before i do anything, i'll check to see if anyone else has put in such a query.  no sense in duplicating unnecessarily.

Comment: @Mico Thank you very much. I was too held up and got an interrupting internet yesterday to edit. :)